# Why Vue3 Composition API - watch’s option deep do not work in reactive, but work in reactive getter?

Tags: vuejs3

1. Arrow function's deep option is work.
2. Raw Reactive Object's deep option is not work.

It looks like a bug, why watch’s option deep do not work in reactive, but work in reactive getter?

1.Code

```
setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      id: 1,
      attrs: {
        date: new Date()
      }
    })

    watch(state, (val, prevVal) => {
      console.log('non-deep', val, prevVal)
    })

    watch(
      () => state,
      (val, prevVal) => {
        console.log('non-deep getter', val, prevVal)
      }
    )

    watch(
      state,
      (val, prevVal) => {
        console.log('deep', val, prevVal)
      },
      { deep: true }
    )

    watch(
      () => state,
      (val, prevVal) => {
        console.log('deep getter', val, prevVal)
      },
      { deep: true }
    )

    const changeDate = () => (state.attrs.date = new Date())

    return {
      state,
      changeDate
    }
  }
```

2.The console logs

```
non-deep Proxy {id: 1, attrs: {…}} Proxy {id: 1, attrs: {…}}
deep Proxy {id: 1, attrs: {…}} Proxy {id: 1, attrs: {…}}
deep getter Proxy {id: 1, attrs: {…}} Proxy {id: 1, attrs: {…}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Vue official document](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers) already points out that:

> When you call watch() directly on a reactive object, it will implicitly create a deep watcher - the callback will be triggered on all nested mutations

### The Answer:

- When you pass a **reactive object (not a getter)** into the `watch` function, the `deep` option will be ALWAYS `true`.
- When you pass a **getter return a reactive object** into the `watch` function, the `deep` should respect your input options and works as expected.

### Extended:

Extended for cases: `Ref`, `ComputedRef`

This is the code inside the `watch` function from the [Vue source code](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/main/packages/runtime-core/src/apiWatch.ts#L207):

```js
if (isRef(source)) {
    getter = () => source.value
    forceTrigger = isShallow(source)
  } else if (isReactive(source)) {
    getter = () => source
    deep = true
  } else if (isArray(source)) {
    isMultiSource = true
    forceTrigger = source.some(isReactive)
    getter = () =>
      source.map(s => {
        ...
      })
  } else if (isFunction(source)) {
    if (cb) {
      // getter with cb
      getter = () =>
        callWithErrorHandling(source, instance, ErrorCodes.WATCH_GETTER)
    }
  ...
}
```

As we can see:

- The **reactive source** will be wrapped in a getter and the deep option will be always `true`
- The **Ref | ComputedRef** source will be wrapped in a getter that returns `source.value` and the `deep` option is the value you passed in. Note that, the value of `ComputedRef` will be replaced each calculation so the `watch` function will be trigger after any change of `ComputedRef` regardless `deep` option
- If you use a getter (function) as the source, Vue will use that getter directly and the `deep` option is the value you passed in

You might ask what kind of my variables? Here is the answer:

```js
const reactiveState = reactive({
  id: 1,
});
// reactiveState is reactive

const refState = ref({
  id: 1,
});
// refState is a Ref
// refState.value is reactive


const computedState = computed(() => {
  return {
    id: reactiveState.id,
  };
});
// computedState is a ComputedRef
// computedState.value is just a raw object without reactive. 
// so calling watch(() => computedState.value, callback) will NOT work
```

See [this code example](https://w6moft.csb.app/) to verify what I said (you should open the dev tool to see the console logs)

Comment: I really have no idea what you are talking about. I respect that you are trying to explain this but it seems you are describing something in very complicated way. Sorry this does not help me at all.

Comment: @Craig It's my bad. But I can't find an easier way to explain it. Sorry for can't help